# Trend Graph Failing to Plot Correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataset:

```
Imputation  Distance    Clustering  2       3       4       5
Multiple    GOWER       PAM         1.6465  1.8604  1.9403  1.8752
Multiple    GOWER       DIANA       1.2760  1.9901  1.9834  1.9330
Multiple    GOWER       AGNES       2.0000  1.9739  1.9711  1.9613
Multiple    DEY         PAM         1.0161  0.7361  1.3657  1.2540
Multiple    DEY         DIANA       2.0000  2.0000  1.9279  1.9081
Multiple    DEY         AGNES       2.0000  2.0000  1.2890  1.2863
Single      GOWER       PAM         1.4669  1.6016  1.8037  1.9244
Single      GOWER       DIANA       1.3779  1.6891  1.6441  1.9429
Single      GOWER       AGNES       1.9630  1.9560  1.9907  1.9436
Single      DEY         PAM         1.0066  0.7093  0.7416  1.2659
Single      DEY         DIANA       1.0340  1.7889  1.7171  1.6917
Single      DEY         AGNES       2.0000  1.6093  1.6088  1.1616
None        GOWER       PAM         1.3351  1.7720  1.8558  1.9137
None        GOWER       DIANA       1.2963  1.9812  1.9420  1.9193
None        GOWER       AGNES       1.7059  1.9190  1.9411  1.9743
```

And I want to plot a graph showing the trend of values from 2 to 5, grouped by the categorical variables in some way.

I have tried melting the dataset thus:

```
molten_cvnn <- melt(cvnn_data, id = c("Imputation", "Distance", "Clustering"))
```

And then tried plotting with a single categorical variable as a group:

```
ggplot(molten_cvnn, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = Imputation)) + geom_line()
```

But this is what I'm getting:
[image: FailedTrend]

I would like to have something like this:

[image]

With a different colour, linetype, shape, etc representing the different category groups.

Thanks for the anticipated help!

Comment: in the molten data, `variable` is a categorical variable with `X2..X5`. Those aren't numbers, what are you hoping them to be? Should they instead be numbers 2 through 5? (Admittedly changing to numbers does not change the plot.)

Comment: Perhaps you want `cvnn_data %>% pivot_longer(cols = `2`:`5`) %>% mutate(rid = rowid(Imputation, name)) %>% ggplot(aes(rid, value, color = name)) + geom_line()`

Comment: Many thanks, @r2evans... They are actually categorical, used to group the values.

Comment: @akrun, Thanks for the help! I have tried to apply the code you suggested, but I keep getting the error `could not find function pivot_longer`. I've tried updating the `tidyverse` package, but it still hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the OP's post, we can reshape to 'long' format, and create the plot

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
cvnn_data %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols = `2`:`5`) %>% 
      mutate(rid = rowid(Imputation, name)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(rid, value, color = name)) + 
         geom_line()
```

---

Or with `ggpubr`

```
library(ggpubr)
names(cvnn_data)[4:7] <- paste0("x", names(cvnn_data)[4:7])
lst1 <- ggline(cvnn_data,  "Imputation", c("x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"), color = "Distance")
lst1[[1]]
lst1[[2]]
```

Or do this with `wrap_plots`

```
library(patchwork)
wrap_plots(lst1)
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun! Any ideas as to why my R studio isn't finding the `pivot_longer` function, please?

Comment: @ayePete can you please check your `packageVersion('tidyr')`

Comment: Thanks so much! I have been able to update the package now. Just had to restart RStudio altogether. I *love* the look of the `ggline` graphs, and I was able to make the information even clearer with a little tweaking. Thanks, once again, for all your help over all the other questions I've asked here on SO. You've been quite the lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two approaches. You can use a line as you want but the number of grouping variables is considerable. So as first instance, I would suggest you using a matrix style plot displayig the lines at different levels.

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(-c(Imputation,Distance,Clustering)) %>%
  mutate(name=gsub('X','',name)) %>%
  group_by(Imputation,Distance,Clustering) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=id,y=value,color=name,group=1))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(Imputation~Distance+Clustering,scales = 'free')
```

Output:

[image]

The second option,as you have distances is using a bar style plot, so that you can see how different they are.

```
#Code 2
df %>% pivot_longer(-c(Imputation,Distance,Clustering)) %>%
  mutate(name=gsub('X','',name)) %>%
  group_by(Imputation,Distance,Clustering) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=id,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black')+
  facet_grid(Imputation~Distance+Clustering,scales = 'free')
```

Output:

[image]

Consider them as options for you.

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Imputation = c("Multiple", "Multiple", "Multiple", 
"Multiple", "Multiple", "Multiple", "Single", "Single", "Single", 
"Single", "Single", "Single", "None", "None", "None"), Distance = c("GOWER", 
"GOWER", "GOWER", "DEY", "DEY", "DEY", "GOWER", "GOWER", "GOWER", 
"DEY", "DEY", "DEY", "GOWER", "GOWER", "GOWER"), Clustering = c("PAM", 
"DIANA", "AGNES", "PAM", "DIANA", "AGNES", "PAM", "DIANA", "AGNES", 
"PAM", "DIANA", "AGNES", "PAM", "DIANA", "AGNES"), X2 = c(1.6465, 
1.276, 2, 1.0161, 2, 2, 1.4669, 1.3779, 1.963, 1.0066, 1.034, 
2, 1.3351, 1.2963, 1.7059), X3 = c(1.8604, 1.9901, 1.9739, 0.7361, 
2, 2, 1.6016, 1.6891, 1.956, 0.7093, 1.7889, 1.6093, 1.772, 1.9812, 
1.919), X4 = c(1.9403, 1.9834, 1.9711, 1.3657, 1.9279, 1.289, 
1.8037, 1.6441, 1.9907, 0.7416, 1.7171, 1.6088, 1.8558, 1.942, 
1.9411), X5 = c(1.8752, 1.933, 1.9613, 1.254, 1.9081, 1.2863, 
1.9244, 1.9429, 1.9436, 1.2659, 1.6917, 1.1616, 1.9137, 1.9193, 
1.9743)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: Many thanks, Duck! This is, I believe, the best I can get given the many categories I have, and it works! I just have to figure out how to get it to work on my system now, because the `R` system isn't finding the `pivot_longer` function.

Comment: Try installing `tidyverse` and then use `library(tidyverse)` to load it!

Comment: @ayePete Or re start a new `R` fresh session and load `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `ggplot2`

Comment: Thanks, @Duck! Starting a fresh R session and updating the packages did the trick!